# Reversing the direction of rotation of a DC cooling fan

Tags: microcontroller, mosfet, dc, fan

We usually connect a small DC cooling fan as show in the diagram. 
[image: Connection schematic for DC cooling fan] 
But is there any method to reverse the rotation of this fan in real time, by adding any external circuits?

Comment: If, by cooling fan, you mean a typical computer case fan, those are not simple DC motors, they typically contain other electronics as well, which would not be very happy with reversed supply polarity. Please share a link to some examples of the fan you have in mind.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh http://www.pavouk.org/hw/fan/en_fan4wire.html

Comment: Yup, those fans contain Brushless DC (BLDC) motors with integrated controllers. They cannot be operated in reverse, nor provided inverted polarity. The easiest solution I can think of is probably physically prying off the fan blades and inverting them, if your particular fans can cope with such torture!

Comment: @Anindo; that won't work either, it will just run the blades with the curvature in the wrong direction so they are continually in stall... you either need to rotate each blade individually, or rewire the internal coils to modify the phase sequence (and hope the position sensor doesn't need modification too!). Or mount the fan on an R-C servo and rotate the lot 180 degrees!

Comment: @BrianDrummond Fair point. I had forgotten that the OP wanted reversal while in operation - so the RC servo sounds like an amusing if accurate "correct solution"!

Comment: Wouldn't using two fans (one for each direction) and selecting which one to use be an easier, more sturdy solution?  (Albeit not a very challenging one).

Comment: @AnindoGhosh Is there any way to find how the internal circuit would look like?

Comment: @noufal The link you provided has photos of the internal circuit board: http://www.pavouk.org/hw/fan/IMG_7118.JPG

Comment: @AnindoGhosh As you pointed out, it's a BLDC. Could you help me to find out the governing equations between speed and torque of the same?

Comment: @noufal It won't be that simple: You would need manufacturer specifications for the BLDC motor, which vary widely.

Answer (score 1):

Bear in mind that the fan blades are shaped for optimum performance in one direction only. Reversing direction will result in more noise and less air flow.